# bootstrap modal doesn't close issue on my one linux server but it works on another linux server

Tags: javascript, java, html, ajax, modal-dialog

My code is working on local server as well as my demo server which is of linux server but its not working on my another linux server I have checked both versions heapsize but still issue occures.

```
        <div id="multiPatDetails" class="modal fade"  role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-md">
              <div class="modal-content">

                <div class="modal-header">
                  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                  <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel" style="text-align:center;">PATIENT DETAIL</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">

                    <input type="hidden" id="apptPatientID1">

                    <div class="row">

                        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" id="patientDetailsListID" style="padding:15px;">

                        </div>

                    </div>

                    <input type="hidden" id="firstNameID">
                    <input type="hidden" id="middleNameID">
                    <input type="hidden" id="lastNameID">
                    <input type="hidden" id="clinicRegNoID">
                    <input type="hidden" id="patMobileNoID">

                    <div class="row" style="margin-top:15px;">

                        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">

                            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
                                <font style="font-size: 14px;">Appointment Date</font>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
                                <input type="text" id="apptDateID2" class="form-control" placeholder="Appointment Date">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
                                <font style="font-size: 14px;">Appt. Start Time</font>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6">

                                <select id="hhID3" class="form-control" style="display: inline-block;width: 48%; padding: 7px;"
                                 onchange="getTimeVal(hhID3.value, mmID3.value, 'apptStartTimeID2', apptDateID2.value, 'startTimeID2');">
                                    <option value="">HH</option>
                                    <%
                                        for(String hours : hoursList){
                                    %>
                                        <option value="<%=hours%>"><%=hours%></option>
                                    <%
                                        }
                                    %>
                                </select>
                                <select id="mmID3" class="form-control" style="display: inline-block;width: 48%; padding: 7px;"
                                 onchange="getTimeVal(hhID3.value, mmID3.value, 'apptStartTimeID2', apptDateID2.value, 'startTimeID2');">
                                    <option value="">MM</option>
                                    <option value="00">00</option>
                                    <option value="05">05</option>
                                </select>

                                <input type="hidden" id="apptStartTimeID2" class="form-control" placeholder="Appt Start Time" readonly="readonly">
                            </div>

                        </div>

                    </div>

                    <div class="row" style="margin-top:15px;">

                        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">

                            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
                                <font style="font-size: 14px;">Appointment Type</font>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6">

                                <select id="apptTypeID2" class="form-control" onchange="getAppointmentDuration(apptTypeID2.value, startTimeID2.value);">
                                    <option value="000">Select Appt. Type</option>

                                <%

                                    for(Integer key: map.keySet()){

                                %>

                                    <option value="<%=key%>"><%=map.get(key)%></option>

                                <%
                                    }
                                %>

                                </select>

                            </div>

                            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
                                <font style="font-size: 14px;">Appointment By</font>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
                                <select id="apptByID2" class="form-control">
                                    <option value="-1">Select Appt. By</option>

                                <%

                                    for(Integer key: clinicianMap.keySet()){

                                %>

                                    <option value="<%=key%>"><%=clinicianMap.get(key)%></option>

                                <%
                                    }
                                %>

                                </select>
                            </div>

                        </div>

                    </div>

                    <div class="row" style="margin-top:15px;">

                        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" align="center">

                            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
                                <font style="font-size: 14px;">Appt. End Time</font>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
                                <input type="text" id="apptEndTimeID2" class="form-control" placeholder="Appt End Time" readonly="readonly">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
                                <font style="font-size: 14px;">Walk In?</font>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
                                <input type="checkbox" name="walkIn" id="walkInID1" value="1" style="zoom: 1.8;">
                            </div>

                        </div>

                    </div>

                    <input type="hidden" name="" id="startTimeID2">
                  <input type="hidden" name="" id="endTimeID2">
                  <input type="hidden" name="" id="agendaID2">
                  <input type="hidden" name="" id="systemStartTimeID2">

                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer" align="center">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick="addNewPatient(firstNameID.value, middleNameID.value, lastNameID.value, clinicRegNoID.value, patMobileNoID.value, apptDateID2.value, apptStartTimeID2.value, systemStartTimeID2.value);">Add New Patient</button>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="multiplePatSubmtBtnID" onclick="registerAppointment3(startTimeID2.value, endTimeID2.value, agendaID2.value, apptPatientID1.value, apptDateID2.value, apptStartTimeID2.value, apptTypeID2.value, apptEndTimeID2.value, '', '', '', '', '', apptByID2.value, systemStartTimeID2.value);" data-dismiss="modal">Add Appointment</button>
                </div>

              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8">
            var xmlhttp;
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            } else {
                xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }

            function registerAppointment(startDate, endDate, agenda, patientID, apptDate, apptStartTime, visitTypeID, apptEndTime, fName, mName, lName, mobileNo, regNo, apptByID, walkIn, currentSystemDateTime) {

                xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {

                        var array = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);

                        var statuMsg = "";

                        for ( var i = 0; i < array.Release.length; i++) {

                            statuMsg = array.Release[i].Msg;

                        }

                        console.log("status msg :: "+statuMsg);

                        if(statuMsg == "Success"){

                            //Retrieving patient details based on patientID
                            //retrievePatientDetails(patientID, startDate, endDate, agenda);
                            //location.reload();
                            window.location.assign("Welcome.jsp");

                            //Calling createEvent function in order to display event added into Calendar
                            //createEvent(startDate, endDate, agenda, "Booked");

                            //$('#singlePatDetails').modal('hide');
                            $('#singlePatDetailsCloseID').click();

                            $('#multiPatDetails').modal('hide');

                            $('#multiPatDetails').removeClass('in');

                            $('#newPatietModal').modal('hide');

                        }else{

                            //$('#singlePatDetails').modal('hide');
                            $('#singlePatDetailsCloseID').click();
                            $('#newPatietModal').modal('hide');
                            $('#multiPatDetails').modal('hide');

                            $("#apptErrorMsgModal").modal('show');

                        }

                    }
                };
                xmlhttp.open("GET", "AddAppointment?visitTypeID="+visitTypeID+"&patientID="+patientID+
                        "&apptDate="+apptDate+"&apptStartTime="+apptStartTime+"&apptEndTime="+apptEndTime+"&walkIn="+walkIn+
                        "&firstName="+fName+"&middleName="+mName+"&lastName="+lName+"&mobileNo="+mobileNo+"&regNo="+regNo+"&cliniciaID="+apptByID+"&startDate="+currentSystemDateTime, true);
                xmlhttp.send();
            }
</script>
```

Comment: please provide details about your error, for example your error log to make it easier to help you

Comment: Thanks for the reply. No error log showing just modal window doesn't close while I click on Add Appointment button, the implementation working fine on background but modal doesn't close so I close it manually by clicking on close button. this issue comes only for one clinic. I have multiple clinics in my application only specific clinic his issue comes for others it works.